# Uploading failed in Xcode 11.2 (11B52) rejected: ITMS-90534: Invalid Toolchain in MacOS Catalina 10.15

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I create build in **Xcode 11.2 (11B52)** & try to uploaded on *APP store* by a Xcode but upload filed with this error

> Dear Developer,
>          We identified one or more issues with a recent submission for App    Store review for your app, "Gözen Security" 7.3.2 (67). Please 
>   correct the following issues, then upload again.
>          ITMS-90534: Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with an    unsupported version of Xcode or SDK. If you plan to submit this build 
>   to the App Store, make sure you are using the GM version of Xcode
>      10.1 and the SDK for iOS 12.1 and watchOS 5.1, Xcode 7.1 and the SDK for tvOS 9, or Xcode 6 and the SDK for macOS 10.9 or later. If you
>   are using an Xcode beta version to test your app, make sure you are
>   using the latest supported version. For more information about
>   supported beta versions, view the App Store Connect What's New page
>   (https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/whats-new/).
>          Best regards,
>          The App Store Team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The only solution is to update xcode 11.2 to xcode 11.2.1** 
If you do not see update in appstore you can download xcode 11.2.1 from here [Download](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
Xcode 11.2 is deprecated by Apple on November 5, 2019